# How do I keep my modal dialog close to the top in both landscape modes objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, modal-dialog, transformation

I'm using this to change the width and height of the modal dialog

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterface {
     if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation)) {

            self.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(74, 170, 380.0f, 712.0f);

        }
}
```

The `self.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(74, 170, 380.0f, 712.0f);` works will on the one landscape but when you turn the iPad around the y position is to low. It needs to be at the same y position for both landscapes.

**edit**

This seams to work. Not sure if its the best answer. Will accept better answers.

```
if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation)) {

            self.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(174, 170, 380.0f, 712.0f);
            self.view.superview.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(self.view.superview.transform,0,-72);

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we are talking here about a UIVIewcontroller presented with the help of PresentModalViewcontroller.
We should not change the height and width of the view controller.
Presentation styles are provided by apple :
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/UIModalPresentationFormSheet

Also if you want to create, custom modal, you can create by transitioning using CATransition on simple UIViews.